# What is "override advice"?

Tags: auctex, info, texinfo

When I execute `describe-mode` from within a `.texi` file, I see:

```
Texinfo/P mode defined in `texinfo.el' (`texinfo-mode'):
:override advice: ‘TeX-texinfo-mode’
```

What happens is that AUCTeX takes over the builtin Texinfo mode.

*Where does that override advice come from? And how do I get back the native Texinfo mode*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Some information about advices

An [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) is mainly a method of last resort to customize the behavior of functions defined in other libraries. There are many variants of advice. Examples are:

- overriding the function with another function (That is the extreme case where one completely replaces the original function.)
- wrapping the original function with an advising function
- filtering the arguments of the original function
- filtering the return value of the original function

Also special hook variables can be advised (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html)).

One should prefer other methods for influencing the behavior of library functions. Often the library developer provides normal and special hook variables. Those have following advantages over advices:

- they are at places where the library developer thinks it is safe to tweak the behavior of the function
- hooks are often well documented by the library developer; often conditions on the hook functions are specified such as whether they may move `point` or change `match-data`

---

## Source of the advice of `texinfo-mode` and how one can avoid it

`TeX-texinfo-mode` comes from the AUCTeX package. It is defined in `tex-info.el`.
Also the override-advice of `texinfo-mode` with `TeX-texinfo-mode` is contained in `tex-info.el`.

You can find that information yourself by the key sequence <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `TeX-texinfo-mode`. (Note that the key sequence <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> is bound to the command `describe-function`.) The link provided with the help page points to the file where the function is defined.

You can get back the old behavior by customizing the variable `TeX-modes` via
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>. You can also use the menu item
`Options` → `Customize Emacs` → `Specific Option...`.

Toggle `texinfo-mode` from the `TeX-modes` list off.

---

## General method to remove an advice

The opt-out of the override of `texinfo-mode` via `TeX-modes` is possible in AUCTeX.

The more general approach to revert the effect of an (override) advice is `advice-remove` after the advising package has been loaded.

This is demonstrated for `texinfo-mode`.
One would put the following code in one's init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'tex-info
  (advice-remove 'texinfo-mode #'TeX-texinfo-mode))
```

**But, you do not need to do that since you have the customization option `TeX-modes`.**

Comment: *Can you complete the answer by explaining what an advice is?* (I just discovered the section about advising functions in the Elisp info pages.)

Comment: Instead of `eval-after-load` with a string first argument, I suggest advertising `with-eval-after-load` with a symbol as its first argument.

Comment: @Basil `with-eval-after-load`is essentially `eval-after-load`. You are right about the feature `'tex-info` instead of the file name.

Comment: @Tobias I know that `with-eval-after-load` is a wrapper around `eval-after-load`, but the former enforces passing an evaluated lambda to the latter. The same commit that introduced `with-eval-after-load` in Emacs 24.4 also changed `eval-after-load` to accept a function argument, rather than an unevaluated form. That's why it's better to recommend the higher-level and better-behaved `with-eval-after-load` wrapper.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks.